# Writing to a file with fstream and cstring

Tags: c++

```
    #include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;


int main()
{
        char filename[20] = "filename";
        char userInput;

        ofstream myFile;


        cout << "Enter filename: ";
        cin.getline(filename, sizeof(filename));


        myFile.open(filename);
        if(myFile.fail())
        {
                cout << "Error opening file: "
                << filename << "\n";
                return 1;

        }

        cout << "Add text to the file: ";
        cin.get(userInput);

        while(cin.good() && userInput)
        {
                myFile.put(userInput);
                cin.get(userInput);

        }


        myFile.close();
        return 0;



}
```

Im having trouble terminating the input without force quiting it(It still writes to the file).

This is what I am supposed to do

Receives a line of input from the user, then outputs that 
line to the given file. This will continue until the line input 
by the user is “-1” which indicates, the end of input.

however I cannot work out the -1 part. Any help would be greatly appreciated everything else seems to work.

Comment: while `while(cin >> userInput)`

Comment: You're returning `1`, not `-1`.

Comment: Im returning 1 if there is a file opening error. Im talking about the file not closing after getting input.

Answer (score 0):

You're making things a bit more complicated than they need to be. Why C strings instead of `std::string`, for example? Using the right (standard-provided) classes generally leads to shorter, simpler and easier-to-understand code. Try something like this for starters:

```
int main()
{
    std::string filename;

    std::cout << "Enter filename" << std::endl;
    std::cin >> filename;

    std::ofstream file{filename};

    std::string line;
    while (std::cin >> line) {
        if (line == "-1") {
            break;
        }
        file << line;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have no choice its part of the course that we are restricted to c-strings at the moment. So I cant use a string.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the assignment asks to read a *line* from the user, character-wise input by `get()` shouldn't be the function to use. Use the member function `getline()` as you did to recieve the file name and use a comparison function to check against `-1`:

```
for (char line[20]; std::cin.getline(line, sizeof line) && std::cin.gcount(); )
{
    if (strncmp(line, "-1", std::cin.gcount()) == 0)
        break;
    myFile.write(line, std::cin.gcount());
}
```